# Why wasn’t Odo surprised that he escaped so easily?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the end of [The Search. Part I](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Search%2C_Part_I_(episode)) episode of DS9,

> USS Defiant sustains heavy damage and is **surrounded by a certain number of Jem'Hadar ships**. Later Odo refers to Defiant's situation as "*dead hole in space*".

My question is, how it was possible, that

> Odo and Kira managed to escape **so easily**, in a small, simple shuttle, from heavily damaged ship, that had no shields and no main power and that was surrounded by many ready to attack enemy ships?

And why wasn't he even surprised, that he managed to do this so easily?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## What does a god need with a shuttlecraft?

It's true that the Defiant was disabled and surrounded by Jem'Hadar, but you are forgetting the fact that the Jem'Hadar had sent a ***boarding party*** to the Defiant:

> **ODO:** You're in a shuttlecraft. You were wounded. Try not to move around.
>
> **KIRA:** Odo, what happened? We were under attack.
>
> **ODO:** ***The ship was boarded.*** You were wounded in the attack. I managed to get us to this shuttlecraft, but I don't know much more than that. The last time I saw the Defiant, she was dead in space and surrounded by Jem'Hadar ships.

The Jem'Hadar would never defy the wishes of a Founder and would certainly never attempt to harm one (regardless of whether Odo knows he is a Founder).  Once they saw Odo come for Kira, they likely stood aside and just let him go.

If a god wants to leave on a shuttlecraft, so be it.

## Odo was in a bit of a drunken stupor.

As for why Odo wasn't surprised at this, note that Odo had been transfixed by the idea of going to the Omarion Nebula from the moment he saw a visual of it, much earlier in the episode:

> **ORNITHAR:** I will need to access one of our computers on the surface.
>
> *(Ornithar calls up a starchart on the viewscreen which interests Odo.)*
>
> **ODO:** What is that?
>
> **ORNITHAR:** It is the Omarion Nebula.
>
> **ODO:** The Omarion Nebula.

And later in the episode, but still before the attack:

> **KIRA:** I'm just trying to return the favour.
>
> **ODO:** Well, you can return the favour by giving me a shuttlecraft and letting me go.
>
> **KIRA:** Go? Go where? We're in the heart of the Dominion. Where the hell do you think you're going to go?
>
> **ODO:** The Omarion Nebula.
>
> **KIRA:** Why?
>
> **ODO:** ***I'm not sure why. I just know I have to, that's all...*** Ever since we've come into the Gamma Quadrant, I've had this feeling of being drawn somewhere, pulled by some instinct to a specific place. The Omarion Nebula.

In other words, Odo seems to be in a stupor regarding getting to the Omarion nebula.  Given his frame of mind, he likely viewed getting off the Defiant as less about saving their lives and more about just getting to the nebula.  In fact, this is pretty much what Odo says:

> **KIRA:** Where are we?
>
> **ODO:** Approaching the Omarion Nebula.
>
> **KIRA:** You should have taken us back to the wormhole.
>
> **ODO:** You didn't object at the time.
>
> **KIRA:** I was unconscious.

Rather than take them back to the wormhole and DS9, Odo took them straight to the nebula, despite Kira's need for medical attention.  Clearly, he wasn't himself.

Comment: I couldn't resist slipping in the *Star Trek V* reference.